# Are you supposed to run automated integration tests against a QA server?

Tags: java, integration-testing

Are you supposed to run automated integration tests against a QA server or are you supposed to somehow start an application server from your tests? Does anyone do option #2? How are you supposed to start an application server from tests?

I'm just running into the dilemma of not knowing where to point my selenium driver to. This is a spring java app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are you supposed to run automated integration tests against a QA
>   server or are you supposed to somehow start an application server from
>   your tests?

As a practical concept, at least the way I see it, the more your test environment(s) looks like your production environment(s), the better. It means that even hardware, location, operational system, etc, have to be considered.

It all comes down to how much "effort" the project is willing to invest on the quality of the product.

You are supposed to run automated integration tests based on your product and project contexts. There isn't a single and final answer to your question, because there are a lot of variables that have to be considered.

> Does anyone do option #2?

Yes, I do use a embedded application server but I only used it for database integration but you can apply that for functional automated testing as well.

> How are you supposed to start an application server from tests?

One option is to use embedded containers that you can manage with Maven profiles. I recommend you to follow this [Arquillian Getting Started](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/) guide to understand how it works, and then you can apply the same concept for Selenium and Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with option 2 -- I use the Maven Jetty Plugin to start an application server running the webapp (usually under a 'test' profile to swap out certain dependencies like the database) and then run Selenium against the locally hosted application. You can bind the Jetty plugin to pre-integration-tests, and stop it in post-integration-tests.

I typically also include the JaCoCo plugin to instrument the Jetty JVM so that I can check coverage from Selenium-style integration tests.